# What does the TM_CCORR and TM_CCOEFF in opencv mean?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

What does the TM_CCORR and TM_CCOEFF in opencv mean? I found that TM_CCORR stands for the correlation coefficient. However, the TM_CCOEFF seams also to be the correlation coefficient due to its naming.

**Do you know for what the abbrevations stand?**

**TM_SQDIFF** = **T**emplate **M**atching **Sq**uare **Diff**erence

**TM_CCOEFF** = **T**emplate **M**atching **C**orrelation **Coeff**icient ?

**TM_CCORR** = **T**emplate **M**atching **Corr**elation ???

Comment: See the [OpenCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d) for the exact formulas.

Comment: Thanks @HansHirse. However, there are only the formulars and not the explanation of the formulars which look quite similar between TM_CCORR and TM_CCOEFF. But what does the abbrevation mean? are both correlation coeffients?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See "Learning OpenCV 3: Computer Vision in C++ with the OpenCV Library"
By Adrian Kaehler, Gary Bradski

https://books.google.com.au/books?id=SKy3DQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT607&ots=XGg5zrJXPp&dq=TM_CCOEFF&pg=PT606#v=onepage&q=TM_CCOEFF&f=false

According to the book:

`TM_CCORR` = Cross correlation

`TM_CCOEFF` = Correlation coefficient

FWIW: The `−1/(w⋅h)⋅∑x″,y″T(x″,y″)` in the `TM_CCOEFF` method is simply used to a) make the template and image zero mean and b) make the dark parts of the image negative values and the bright parts of the image positive values.

This means that when bright parts of the template and image overlap you'll get a positive value in the dot product, as well as when dark parts overlap with dark parts (-ve value x -ve value gives +ve value).
That means you get a +ve score for both bright parts matching and dark parts matching.

When you have dark on template (-ve) and bright on image (+ve) you get a -ve value. And when you have bright on template (+ve) and dark on image (-ve) you also get a -ve value.
This means you get a negative score on mismatches.

On the other hand if you don't have the `−1/(w⋅h)⋅∑x″,y″T(x″,y″)` term, i.e. in `TM_CCORR` method, then you don't get any penalty when there are mismatches between the template and the image. Effectively this method is measuring where you get the brightest set of pixels in the image that are the same shape to the template. (That's why the logo, the soccer ball and area above Messi's leg have high intensity in the matching result).

Answer (score 8):

As HansHire mentions, the [official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d) presents the formulas used for pixel summing as the windows slide. Additionally the [Python OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) show examples:

```
TM_CCOEFF
```

[image: TM_COEFF]

```
TM_CCORR
```

[image: TM_CORR]

Take note that docs say:

> You can see that the result using cv2.TM_CCORR is not good as we expected.

If you want to use screenshots or sections of images(a-la [Sikuli](http://up.csail.mit.edu/sikuli/demo.shtml)) that always stay the same (not real-world camera frames where lighting/transformations can change) then use `matchTemplate`, otherwise try to avoid it. It's very good for specific use cases only and there is not a huge difference between the different summing functions in terms of practical results.

To address your comment on  what the abbrevations `TM_CCORR` and `TM_CCOEFF` Stand for?:

To be 100% I don't honestly know, but that won't stop me from having a guess :)))

My hunch, based on documentation formulas is that `TM_CCORR` is the direct ("simplest") correlation between template and image:

result pixel is the sum of the dot product of between the template pixel and and image pixel for each pixel in the template.

As the template "slides" through the image, the result image is computed.

`TM_CCOEFF` but instead of current template pixel (`T`) a more complex "coefficient"(`T'`) is used (`T(x′,y′)−1/(w⋅h)⋅∑x″,y″T(x″,y″)`) (which similarly (`I'` uses).

My understanding of math notation is quite limited, but as as far I can tell from the formula, the `CORR` version as opposed the `COEFF` takes into account the dimensions of the template and image along with the sum of the pixel intensities.

The only other supported method is `TM_SQDIFF` which as the shorthand name implies and formula confirms uses the squared distance between template and image pixel intensities.

For each of these 3 main methods there are normed versions.

Ok, that's my take on what the abbreviation means (e.g. direct(dot product) correlation versus a more convoluted (no pun intended) correlation )

But that does it mean ?

In practical terms, I would mainly pay attention to the fact that `TM_CCORR` and `TM_CCOEFF` make the most likely match to the brightest pixel while `TM_SQDIFF` is the opposite: darkest values are likely matches (see example images linked).

I would start with `TM_CCOEFF` then if the results for the current images don't return consistent results fiddle with the parameters, but as mentioned earlier I'd use this only for very **very** controlled conditions.

For live data that's not screenshots or templates that are section of the same image (a-la "where's Waldo") I'd look into object detection (e.g. training an SVM using HOG as the feature descriptor)

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know for what the abbrevations TM_CCORR and TM_CCOEFF Stand for?

Comment: Appreciate the thoroughness you're pursuing this with, I've provided more info above. Hopefully it covers the practicals. If you really want to go down rabbit holes for this one: option 1 if you're happy with c++ look at the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp#L437), option 2: use a language you prefer and write your own correlation functions, test them with raw numbers first, then write another method that can traverse all img pixels to then traverse all template pixels per image pixels, compute correlation and store result.

Answer (score 0):

Following formula gives a centered version of T(x,y):

T′(x′,y′)=T(x′,y′)−1/(w⋅h)⋅∑x′′,y′′T(x′′,y′′)

Is a little bit different with I′, as it centers I within kernel (w, h).

I′(x+x′,y+y′)=I(x+x′,y+y′)−1/(w⋅h)⋅∑x′′,y′′I(x+x′′,y+y′′)

I think ideally TM_CCORR_NORMED and TM_CCOEFF_NORMED should give similar results.
The difference might occur due to computer rounding, as TM_CCOEFF_NORMED generally operates with numbers closer to zero.

**Update**

T' = T - m, where m is a mean value of T

I' = I - I * M, where M is mean filter matrix of size (w, h)

```
TM_CCOEFF  = T' * I' = (T - m) * (I - I * M) =
           = ((T - m) * I) * (U - M)
           = TM_CCORR * SHARPNESS - m * (I * SHARPNESS)
```

where U - is unit filter, and SHARPNESS = U - M is sharpness filter.

So, TM_CCOEFF is sharpness of TM_CCORR with some normalization.